# Read specific file in Time Capsule from someone else's computer

Tags: backup, time-machine, time-capsule

I recently lost my macbook, and fortunately I have all my backups in a Time Capsule. At the moment I only have an old window PC, and a friend who has a macbook.

The question is: how do we recover the files on the Time Capsule thanks to the macbook in order to copy them into my old PC ?

We tried to navigate to the data on the TimeCapsule (i.e. `/Volumes/Data/my-computer.sparsebundle`) we see the `bands` folder that seems to contain the data, but we are not able to see its contents with the `Finder`. Is there any way to do something like "mount" the `my-computer.sparsebundle` in order to navigate into it ?

We connected to the Time Capsule with Wi-Fi, and  my friend runs on a macbook with OS X 10.11.4.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the answer to my problem from the Apple Technical support. A double click on the file `my-computer.sparsebundle` should mount the Time Capsule as a Time Machine virtual disk. It didn't work in my case. The guy from the Apple support just told me to reboot the Time Capsule. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Head into Finder. On the same Wifi network as your Time Capsule, scroll down to the "Shared" section in Finder's left sidebar. There will be an icon of a Time Capsule with the name of your Time Capsule next to it. Click it, and you should be able to easily navigate through (just keep double-clicking on the relevant things) to your files.